# How to get Column Names and other information from SqlServer table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2008

I need to get Column Names along with other information like

```
DATA_TYPE, CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH ,NUMERIC_PRECISION, NUMERIC_SCALE, IS_NULLABLE, IS_IDENTITY,ORDINAL_POSITION , Primary Key from table
```

I have use following query for that

```
Select  C.COLUMN_NAME as 'ColumnName',
        C.DATA_TYPE as 'Datatype', 
        C.CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH as 'MaxLength',
        C.NUMERIC_PRECISION as 'Precision',
        C.NUMERIC_SCALE as 'Scale',
        C.IS_NULLABLE as 'Is_NULL',
        C.IS_IDENTITY,
        C.ORDINAL_POSITION as 'Position',
        isnull(Z.CONSTRAINT_NAME,0) as 'PrimaryKey'
From INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS As C 
Outer Apply (
    Select CCU.CONSTRAINT_NAME 
    From INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS As TC 
    Join INFORMATION_SCHEMA.CONSTRAINT_COLUMN_USAGE As CCU 
        On CCU.CONSTRAINT_NAME = TC.CONSTRAINT_NAME
    Where TC.TABLE_SCHEMA = C.TABLE_SCHEMA And 
          TC.TABLE_NAME = C.TABLE_NAME And 
          TC.CONSTRAINT_TYPE = 'PRIMARY KEY' And 
          CCU.COLUMN_NAME = C.COLUMN_NAME ) As Z 
Where C.TABLE_NAME = 'tablename'
```

**the issue is with C.IS_IDENTITY if i remove it then query works fine**

Please Suggest me how can i get identity info with this query

Answer (score 2):

For `IS_IDENTITY` use the below expression in your select query

```
COLUMNPROPERTY(object_id('tablename'), C.COLUMN_NAME, 'IsIdentity')
```